Problems with distributed package
I have been having troubles using the Distributed package. I have one function that returns a 100 x 4 array. This array is produced by averaging over some dimensions of a SharedArray that is constructed with a distributed for, the code looks something like
@everywhere function GenerateMatrix(H::sparsearray, indices::Array{Int}, a::Float64)
   Gavg = SharedArray{Float64}(100, length(indices))
   Z = Array{Float64}(undef, 100, 4)
   G = lu(a*sparse(I, size(H)) - H) #new array, same size as H
   @sync @distributed for i=1:length(indices)
          main_ind = indices[i]
          Gmain = G[:, main_ind]
           ...
          #Other for operations that fill the matrix Gavg
    end
    Z[:,1] = mean(G_avg, dims=2)
    #And other operations up to Z[:,4]
    return Z
 end

This function has no problems whatsover by itself, the problem comes when I try to generate several of these Z arrays and average them over and over, rewriting the same file and saving as checkpoints every factor of 1000, as follows
using DelimitedFiles
function IterateFiles(a::Float64, N)
        for j=1:N
             ...
             #Create H and the respective indices vector
             Z = GenerateMatrix(H, indices, a)
             if j==1
                 writedlm("Z_sample"*string(j), Z)
             else
                Zprev = readdlm("Z_sample"*string(j-1))
                Ztemp = (Zprev *(j-1)+ Z)/j  
                writedlm("Z_sample"*string(j), Ztemp)
                if (j-1)%1000 != 0 #this deletes the previous file unless it corresponds to a checkpoint
                   rm("Z_sample"*string(j-1)) 
                end
        end

This code excutes just fine and produce files as expected, however it stops producing files after (a random number) of several iterations of the function IterateFiles. It does not produce an error message. When I check the workers with ps auxr in the terminal, at the beginning shows that the program is working just fine and the selected number of processors with the distributed are being used, but a bit after ps auxr just displays the original instruction sent but no other workers from the distributed, and after this happens no new files are produced.
I though it was an memory error but that doesn't seem to be the problem. There's no error message nor the main instruction to run the code stops, julia -p 8 code.jl still appears as an outgoing work but is no longer producing results.
I have no clue of what can be going on. I'd greatly appreciate any insight or help you can provide to this.

You are doing I/O on files, so it is possible that you are failing to catch a thrown error, due to a file you reference being missing, empty, or inaccessible. You could add a lock and try/catch to readdlm and writedlm. If (as I assume here) the code outside of your delimited file handling is the slow step you want to multithread, you could just wrap the file handling with a lock (the lock can be removed if you are not going to multithread this step):
using DelimitedFiles

rlock = ReentrantLock()

function IterateFiles(a::Float64, N)
    for j=1:N

        #Create H and the respective indices vector
        Z = GenerateMatrix(H, indices, a)
        try
            lock(rlock)
            if j == 1
                writedlm("Z_sample"*string(j), Z)
            else
                Zprev = readdlm("Z_sample"*string(j-1))
                Ztemp = (Zprev *(j-1)+ Z)/j  
                writedlm("Z_sample"*string(j), Ztemp)
            end
            if (j-1)%1000 != 0 #this deletes the previous file unless it corresponds to a checkpoint
                rm("Z_sample"*string(j-1)) 
            end
            unlock(rlock)
        catch y
            @warn y
            unlock(rlock)
            rethrow()
        end
    end
end

